# Inertiajs not sending inputs through parameters [Laravel 9]

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, inertiajs

I'm sending a `put/patch` request to backend (Inertiajs to Laravel). but the parameter bag is empty and all the inputs shows up in `content` attribute of `request object`.

```js
// in frontend [Inertiajs]
form.patch(route('posts.update', props.post.id), options);
// form.put(route('posts.update', props.post.id), options); // same as patch method
```

```php
// in backend Laravel
dd(request());
```

result:

```
Illuminate\Http\Request :
    request:
        parameters: []



    content:
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryLAUcPkq3YTjgwsCM
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"
    
    "some title"
```

now `dd(request('title'))` give me `null`.

what should I do to the code for sending the inputs through request parameters?

Comment: use POST instead of put/patch in inertiajs with an input `_method="patch"` or `_method="put"`

Answer (score 1):

There is some multipart limitations. As Inertia says [here](https://inertiajs.com/file-uploads#:%7E:text=Multipart%20limitations), uploading files using a `multipart/form-data` request is not natively supported in some languages for the `put`, `patch` or `delete` methods. The workaround here is to simply upload files using post instead.

In your case, would look something like this:

```js
form.post(route('posts.update', {
  _method: 'put',
  postId: props.post.id,
})
```

* Do it like this if you want to preserve the scroll:

```js
form.post(route('posts.update', {
  _method: 'put',
  postId: props.post.id,
}, {
  preserveScroll: true,
})
```